# Ubuntu 15.10 download

Tags: downloads

I downloaded Ubuntu 15.10 desktop software from its official website which was in a winrar file. I have been having problems to convert to a iso disc image file. Is there a link where i can download the iso file directly.

Comment: You can directly download the iso file here [Ubuntu 15.10 desktop (amd64)](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?version=15.10&architecture=amd64) - I don't know where you got a .rar file from?

Comment: The file you have will be an .iso, it is just that you have set winRAR file association on .iso files. Right click the file and check the extension.

Comment: You have downloaded an iso file, however your computer is set to open .iso files with WinRar. You do not need to open that file, neither do you need to get confused if you see an icon of WinRAR on the iso file. You can see how to install Ubuntu on a Pre-installed Windows PC from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-wit‌​h-uefi).

Answer (score 0):

This is the download link for Ubuntu 15.10 desktop 64bit: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?version=15.10&architecture=amd64

Just download that. **Ignore what WinRAR says.**

Next, you burn the ISO file to a DVD. In a recent Windows version: right-click on the file you downloaded, and choose 'Open with > Windows Disc Image Burner'. That's all there is to it.